# Custom Rounding of decimal type in C#

Tags: c#, rounding

Guys,
I am writing a method for rounding. Input is a decimal type (four decimal places guaranteed). The rounding rule is that 0.005 or less is ignored, i.e. look at third decimal place - if it is <= 5, round down else round up.
Some use cases : 82.3657 -> 82.36, 82.3667 -> 82.37, 82.5967 -> 82.60, 82.9958 -> 82.99, 82.9968 -> 83.00
Any good ideas? I have worked it out as follows.

```
private decimal CustomRound(decimal x)
{
   decimal rX = Math.Truncate(x * 100) / 100;
   decimal x3DecPlaces = Math.Truncate(x * 1000) / 1000;
   decimal t = (x3DecPlaces * 1000) % 10;
   if (t >= 6)
      rX = rX + 0.01m;
   return rX;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't believe there's anything built-in for that, because it's a pretty unusual requirement (for example the idea that 1.3358 is closer to 1.33 than to 1.34 is odd). Your code looks reasonably appropriate.

EDIT: You can't use `MidpointRounding` to get the effect you want here, because the point at which you start rounding up *isn't* the midpoint - it's (say) 1.336 rather than the normal 1.335. Only 1.335 is treated as the midpoint between 1.33 and 1.34, because that *is* the mid-point. You've effectively got a biased rounding here in an unusual way.

You can't even just truncate to three DP and then use `MidpointRounding`, as there's no "towards zero" mode.

One slightly odd option would be to effectively perform the bias yourself:

```
private static decimal CustomRound(decimal x)
{
    return decimal.Round(x - 0.001m, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
}
```

So it would treat 82.3657 as 82.3647 and round that to 82.36; it would treat 82.3667 and 82.3657 and round it to 82.37, and it would treat 82.5967 as 82.5957 and round it to 82.60 etc. I *think* that does what you want - but only for positive values. You'd need to work out exactly what behaviour you want for negative values.

Whatever you do, you need to document it very clearly :)

Just as a matter of preference, I would use `decimal.Truncate` rather than `Math.Truncate`, just to make it clearer that everything really is done with decimals.

Comment: Yes, I struggled with trying to use built in methods. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

How do you want to handle negative values? I suppose you would want -13.999 to round to -14 not to -13.99 right?

In that case your `+/- 0.01m` should depend on whether `x` is negative or positive.

This is an easier way to do it:

```
decimal CustomRound(decimal x)
{
    var offset = x >= 0 ? -0.001m : 0.001m;
    return Decimal.Round(x + offset, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe You could use Math.Round(Double, Int32) Method?

Comment: Converting from decimal to double and then back again is a terrible idea - it means it's pretty much pointless to use decimal to start with.

Comment: @Jon: there's an [overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131275.aspx) of `Math.Round` working with Decimals.

Comment: @Vlad: Sure, but this answer specifically calls out the overload using double.